# What are the requirements when we want change an ETL job from one server to another server?

Tags: ssis

I am new to ssis. We are trying to change server from of ETL job can please give me the whole procedure where all the places we need change connections.

Comment: That of course would be difficult to do without seeing the actual SSIS package.

Answer (score 2):

A tip going forward when you create your next package (or an opportunity to modify the one in question) is to make all connections dynamic based on project or package parameters.

Note:  This tip assumes you are using version 2012 or above as there is an different solution for older versions.

Making connections dynamic allows deploying to a new server with no changes needed to the packages themselves. This is also an SSIS best practice as you never want to have to modify a package to merely move across servers or environments. You can make connections dynamic by merely adding a project parameter and then using that parameter in an expression for your connection property (such as the Servername property for an Oledb connection) that refers to the project parameter. Then at runtime whatever is passed in the project parameter is what is used for your connection. SSIS environments can also provide automatic values for the project parameters if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to give a complete step by step on this without having the package in front of me but some possible places to look:

- The connection in the package
- The configuration
- The variables
- Any script task which might reference the server directly
- Any Execute SQL task that might include SQL that uses a linked server
  in addition to the connection the SQL runs from. This might include researching the code run in any stored procedure run in the server.
- Any job script you have that deploys to the old server, to properly
  set up the new one.

Of course you would want to adjust (set up if you don't have them) unit tests to make sure that any changes you make in the dev environment go to the correct new neev locations. And have QA check to see if the data goes to/comes from  the correct locations. If you are doing your work correctly,they should already have test cases which will need adjusting for the new server. You can use your unit tests to check the first prod run as well to make sure there were no configuration mistakes in moving to prod.

Comment: Thank you very much HLGEM .. ..can you please assist me in 

1.)I have a job script in old server .it is require to copy the older one to the new server.

2)After running jobs in log files  I have observed that it is retrieving data from older  version only. after changing my server to new server.

3).can I able to view This package at visual studio level to make some modifications.at presently the package am viewing in management studio level.